# Integrity Error in Django where project has two user table?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I am facing a problem in Django admin panel, when I want to add or delete or update any value I got this error,

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child
>   row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_name`.`django_admin_log`,
>   CONSTRAINT `django_admin_log_user_id_c564eba6_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`))')

In my project, there are two user tables, one that was created in the first migration after that I create a `custom user` model. It works fine in local but facing problems in the server.
As Django used InnoDB by default all my table is in InnoDB (I find some solution like this if I convert the table engine to MyISAM it'll solve the problem), I have plenty of data in the database and I can't do any test operation in it.

Comment: Please show us the user models. You more than likely have missed a setup phase in the generating of the custom user table.

Comment: It's an issue with my MySQL setup in project settings

Answer (score 0):

just change my project settings database

```
'OPTIONS': {
         "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;",
    }
```

and that's solved my problem.

Thank you all